# Как расставить символы в данном примере в js

Tags: javascript

```
var symbol = "*";
var empty = "";
var count  = 10;


**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Мне нужно чтобы эти символы выводились построчно в `console.log(**********);`

как продумать эту логику, когда интерпретатор натыкается на цифру 10(в контексте этого примера, данная цифра пока статична), чтоб он создал новую строчку `console.log(**********);` и так  10 раз! какое условие нужно для этого,
я думаю, здесь что-то связано с делением по модулю, но так и не разработал саму логику! Всем за ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы наверное это имеете в виду?

```
Array(count) // Мы тут создаем массив из `count` элементов
.fill(symbol) // заполняем его Вашим символом
```

И для каждого элемента выполняем:

```
console.log(s.repeat(count)) // повторить символ `count` раз и вывести в консоль
```

в результате получается матрица `10х10`

```js
var symbol = "*";
var count  = 10;

Array(count).fill(symbol).forEach(s => {
    console.log(s.repeat(count));
});
```

Comment: представьте, что это шахматная доска! Вот такого же образца надо

Comment: а почему symbol.length == 1?? мне надо что общее количество было равен 100

Comment: @John у Вас еще остались вопросы?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var symbol = "*";
var empty = "";
var count  = 10;

for(let i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < count ; j++) {
    empty += symbol;
  }
  console.log(empty);
  empty = '';
}
```

Или что нужно? Не совсем понятно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, сейчас исходник приложу

Comment: Вот так ещё могу придумать.